# hibernate query запрос

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, запрос

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать запрос если:
есть "проэкт" у него есть флаг-поле и руководитель (связь один к одному). Руководитель - Entity-объект. Так не работает. Спасибо.

```
public List<Project> getList(boolean status, User manager){
    Query query = null;
    if(status){
        mySql = "SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.status is true ";
    }else{
        mySql = "SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.status is false ";
    }

    mySql += "and join p.manager m WHERE m.username=:username";
    query = em.createQuery(mySql,Project.class);
    query.setParameter("username", manager.getUsername());
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

так тоже...

```
 public List<Project> getList(boolean status, User manager){
    Query query = null;
    if(status){
        mySql = "SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.status is true ";
    }else{
        mySql += "SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.status is false ";
    }

    mySql = "and join p.manager m WHERE m.username=:username";
    query = em.createQuery(mySql,Project.class);
    query.setParameter("username", manager.getUsername());
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сначала вы инициализируете `mySql` (объявления которой, кстати не видно, видимо она является полем объекта.)

```
if(status){
    mySql = "SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.status is true ";
}else{
    mySql = "SELECT p FROM Project p WHERE p.status is false ";
}
```

После чего заменяете все в этой строке:

```
mySql = "and join p.manager m WHERE m.username=:username";
```

Вероятно вы хотели дополнить текст так:

```
mySql += "and join p.manager m WHERE m.username=:username";
```

Что касается самого запроса: дополните вопрос описанием таблиц и напишите что конкретно должно быть в результате запроса. В данном виде он не выполнится.